# Docker file size problems

Tags: docker

I am reading file under docker with linux:

```
fp = fopen(_path, "r");  
readCnt = fread(buffer, 1, payloadLen, fp);  
//payloadLen = 10240  
//readCnt = 8993
```

while when I'am calling stat on file I get:

```
$ stat /tmp/vc.bin  
File: /tmp/vc.bin  
Size: 10240         Blocks: 24         IO Block: 4096   regular file  
Device: 35h/53d Inode: 96          Links: 1  
Access: (0644/-rw-r--r--)  Uid: ( 1000/builduser)   Gid: ( 1000/builduser)  
Access: 2017-03-27 06:57:19.272826554 +0000  
Modify: 2017-03-27 06:57:19.272826554 +0000  
Change: 2017-03-27 11:33:42.125708017 +0000  
Birth: -
```

st_size from stat call is 8993.
Any ideas why docker behaves like this?

Comment: That reported size is on a nice round byte boundary, but then doesn't match 24 blocks.  What storage system are you using in docker? What filesystem is `/tmp` on in the container?

Comment: @Matt:
$ df -h /tmp 
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
none            474G  297G  153G  67% /
I am not sure if it should look like this...

Comment: `docker info | grep Storage` ?

Comment: $ docker info | grep Storage  
    Storage Driver: aufs  
    WARNING: No swap limit support

Comment: Ok, problem solved, docker works fine.
It is shame that after week of digging you find out that colleague in meantime changes content of file, and then restores it:/